# A Strange Spin on Arranging Letter Combinations

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I was recently asked by a math nerd friend about the possible configurations of the letters **ARRANGE**. That is a problem which has been beat to death, but specifically, how many configurations are there if you **don't** need to use all the letters allowing for 6 and 5 and so on letter long words. Naturally, each letter can be used up to as many time it appears in the word ARRANGE.

I couldn't think of a good way to do this with the choose function or variations of the "must use all letters" 7!/(2!*2!).

Comment: Hint: add an extra character (like `!`) to signal end-of-word, and count the permutations of the characters `ARRANGE!`. Be sure to decide whether you want to count the word with no letters!

Comment: Are you aware of exponential generating functions ?

Comment: @GregMartin: I'll say "no" on the grounds that it probably wouldn't have worked on my high school English teachers.  "You didn't meet the required minimum word count."  "But I did!  I just used a lot of zero-length words."

Comment: I'm curious how the end-of-word character solution is supposed to work. If ARRAN!GE and ARRAN!EG both represent the word ARRAN, how do we avoid double-counting it (without a bunch of casework as in the posted answer)?

Comment: Welcome to this site! If the issue has been resolved, do consider [accepting](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/why-should-we-accept-answers) ✔ and upvoting ▲ answers: this signals resolution, prevents the page from being bumped, scores points, and influences the site's search results, cleanup activities, and other behind-the-scenes processes.

Answer (score 3):

### 6 letters

Not including N,G,E: $\quad3\cdot\frac{6!}{2!2!}=540$
Not including A or R: $\quad2\cdot\frac{6!}{2!}=720$

### 5 letters

Not including both A's or both R's: $\quad2\cdot\frac{5!}{2!}=120$
Not including 2 among N,G,E: $\quad3\cdot\frac{5!}{2!2!}=90$
Not including an A and a R: $\quad5!=120$
Not including one among N,G,E and one among A,R: $\quad3\cdot2\cdot\frac{5!}{2!}=360$

### 4 letters

Having only A and R: $\quad\frac{4!}{2!2!}=6$
Having 2 A's or 2 R's and 2 among R/A,N,G,E: $\quad2\cdot6\cdot\frac{4!}{2!}=144$
All 4 unique: $\quad5\cdot4!=120$

### 3 letters

All 3 unique: $\quad10\cdot3!=60$
Only 2 unique: $\quad2\cdot4\cdot\frac{3!}{2!}=24$

### 2 letters

Both same: $\quad2\cdot\frac{2!}{2!}=2$
Both unique: $\quad10\cdot2!=20$

### 1 letter

Number of ways: $5$

### Total:

**Answer** $\begin{align} &= (\text{Sum of all of the above cases}) \\ &= 1260+690+270+84+22+5 \\ &= 2331 \end{align}$

---

**Note**: Numbers without "$!$" are selections and the latter part is the arrangement of those selected letters.

---

Since, the language of the question isn't too clear on this part so, in case, 7 letter words are also allowed then:

### 7 letters

Number of words: $\quad\frac{7!}{2!2!}=1260$

**Total**$= 3591$

---

**Thanks to** [**@DanielMathias**](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/627720/daniel-mathias) for proof-reading the answer.

Comment: You have omitted AARN and similar words.

Comment: @DanielMathias thanks a lot! Great eye for detail. Silly mistake by me. Corrected.

Comment: For that case, you should have $2\times\binom42\times\frac{4!}{2!}=144$. In your 5-letter cases you should have $3\times\frac{5!}{2!2!}=90$. (I only noticed that because your totals did not agree with enumeration via code.) You should also include the 7-letter permutations.

Comment: @DanielMathias silly mistakes is almost like a shadow to me, but thanks to you for providing me with light to cast it away! Also, 7-letter permutations were a bit dubious from the language whether to be included or not especially because of the emboldened "don't" though I've included that too for the completeness of the question.